# How can I remove duplicates from list of list in python quickly?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a large nested list structure:

```
   t = [
        [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]],
        [['d', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]],
        [['g', 1], ['h', 2], ['i', 3]]
    ]
```

I want to remove all duplicates of the inner-most list.

This function works well:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3], ['g', 1], ['i', 3]]
```

BUT is very slow for my huge list. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
def get_unique_list(seq):
    flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
    seen = []
    return [x for x in flat_list if x not in seen and not seen.append(x)]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use a `dictionary`

```
seen = {}
ret = []
for item in flat_list:
    if tuple(item) not in seen:
        ret.append(item)
        seen[tuple(item)] = True
return ret
```

Comment: The first gives a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', and why would the second be faster than a comprehension?

Comment: My bad, the list is unhashable. the 2nd will give an error too. so changing it to tuple before marking as seen. The second should be faster because it is a dictionary which is a hashmap.

Comment: With a small change this works and is much faster!

Comment: when seen was an array, the search complexity was O(array size). But when using a dictionary, it should be O(1), so it's faster. Though when the hashmap faces collision, the time complexity may degrade

Answer (score 0):

Since dict keys are unique in Python, you can use a dict comprehension over the inner lists, convert each inner list to a tuple to make it hashable to become the key, and the original inner list as the value, and output the values of the dict as a list:

```
list({tuple(i): i for s in t for i in s}.values())
```